# Linked List Implementation - using separate Insert(), Delete(), Print() functions

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement Linked List on C++ by utilizing three separate functions:

1. Insert(int x, int n) - Takes the number to be inserted (x) and the position to be inserted at (n) starting with position 1.
2. Delete(int n) - Deletes the number at position (n) starting with position 1;
3. Print() - Prints the elements of the linked list.

Here is my code in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* head;

void Print()
{
    cout << "The List is:" ;
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp -> next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp -> next;
        cout << " " << temp -> data;
    }
}

void Delete(int n)
{
    if ( n == 1 )
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        head = temp -> next;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }

    Node* temp1 = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++)
    {
        temp1 = temp1 -> next;
    }

    Node* temp2 = temp1 -> next;
    temp1 -> next = temp2 -> next;
    delete temp2;
}

void Insert(int x, int n)
{
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp -> data = x;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    if ( n == 1 )
    {
        temp -> next = head;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    Node* temp1 = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-2; i++)
    {
        temp1 = temp1 -> next;
    }


    temp -> next = temp1 -> next;
    temp1 -> next = temp;
}

int main()
{
    head = NULL;

    Insert(2,1);
    Insert(3,1);
    Insert(99,3);
    Insert(4,2);
    Insert(5,3); // 3, 4, 5, 99, 2 

    Print(); // 1st call

    Delete(2);
    Delete(3); // 3,5,2

    Print(); // 2nd call

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, according to my configuration, 1st call of the print function produces 4, 5, 2, 99 instead of 3, 4, 5, 2, 99. Also the second call shows 5, 99.

Comment: I would highly recommend indexing your list by 0, not 1.  That's almost always the standard.  You don't want your code to be confusing.

Comment: I would highly recommend using a debugger.

Comment: You have a debugger, learn how to use it!

Comment: Actually I have indexed by 0 only (as is evident from the for loop), but used 1 base for 'positioning' and thus run my code till (n-2) @TrippKinetics

Comment: "Positioning" and "Indexing" are the same thing.  Follow the rule of least astonishment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your print function, try this:

```
void Print()
{
    cout << "The List is:";
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << " " << temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

You need to print till temp itself is not `NULL`.
And in C++ I suggest using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!
I also needed to cout the last element separately after the while loop!
Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

The two lines in the while loop, in the print function are inverted. You are moving your pointer to the next element and then printing, so you never print the first. Your function must look like this:

```
void Print()
{
    cout << "The List is:" ;
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp -> next != NULL)
    {
        cout << " " << temp -> data;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct!
I also needed to cout the last element separately after the while loop!
Thanks for your input :)
@Cristian Yones

Comment: Not quite. This would cause the last element to be skipped, instead of the first element. The other answer, checking whether temp is null instead of temp->next, in addition to printing before incrementing, is correct.